# Why doesn't the fitted straight line fit the graph?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Take this simple code to fit a straight line through a set of points:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Polynomial = np.polynomial.Polynomial
def fitcurve(sequence, startx):
     return Polynomial.fit(range(startx, startx+len(sequence)), sequence, 1)
interval = [1361273, 1258363, 1448623, 1524331, 1546994, 1521276, 1535427]
c, m = fitcurve(interval, 0)
x = np.arange(0, len(interval))
y = c+m*x
plt.plot(interval)
plt.plot(x, y)
```

The result is:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see any documentation for polynomial.fit. https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit.html#numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit.   assuming it's the same as polyfit the way you are using c looks wrong. It should be an array of coefficients. In your case 2 for the constant and the slope.

Comment: @gph Thanks. Yes Stef has explained my error.

Comment: I started writing my comment and got distracted before I finished. It took a while to come back so I didn't see that answer. Glad you got it worked out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`fit`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit.html#numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit) returns a new polynomial, not the coefficients. To get the coefficients use `convert().coef`:

```
p = fitcurve(interval, 0)
a = p.convert().coef
x = np.arange(0, len(interval))
y = a[0]+a[1]*x
```

[image]